# Play framework: How to process server errors in HTTP filters?

Tags: http, logging, error-handling, playframework

I am trying to create an HTTP filter that logs some info about the request, say headers, and a limited (so the memory doesn't explode) part of the request body in case of an error.

To do that I've followed the docs (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters) and came up with something like this:

```
class RequestErrorLogFilter @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends EssentialFilter {

  private val logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("application.AccumulatorFlowFilter")

  private implicit val logging = Logging(actorSystem.eventStream, logger.getName)

  override def apply(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    override def apply(request: RequestHeader): Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = {
      val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = next(request)

      val data = ArrayBuffer.empty[ByteString]
      var totalSize = 0
      val maxSize = 1024

      val flow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = Flow[ByteString]
        .map((in: ByteString) => {
          val left = maxSize - totalSize
          if (left > 0) {
            val takeNow =
              if (in.size > left) {
                in.slice(0, left)
              } else {
                in
              }
            data.append(takeNow)
            totalSize += takeNow.size
          }
          in
        })

      val accumulatorWithResult = accumulator.through(flow).map { result =>
        // this code doesn't get executed in case of an exception in a controller
        logger.info(s"The flow has completed and the result is $result")
        if (result.header.status >= 400) {
          val headerText = data.map(_.utf8String).mkString("")
          logger.warn(s"There was an error. Request head: $headerText")
        }
        result
      }

      accumulatorWithResult
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for client errors (like 400 - bad request), or for any error returned from a controller, but in case of an exception inside of a controller, filter's "callback" isn't executed, so there's no opportunity to log what happened.

And there's a same problem with a much simpler "AccessLogHttpFilter" which I think is a recommended solution to create an access log with play applications:

```
class LoggingFilter @Inject() (val mat: Materializer, implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and " +
        s"returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make play invoke http filter code even in case of exceptions?
Is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

For an EssentialFilter to handle an error you need to add a .recover() call to an accumulator:

```
class RequestErrorLogFilter @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends EssentialFilter {

  private val logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("application.AccumulatorFlowFilter")

  private implicit val logging = Logging(actorSystem.eventStream, logger.getName)

  override def apply(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    override def apply(request: RequestHeader): Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = {
      val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = next(request)

      val data = ArrayBuffer.empty[ByteString]
      var totalSize = 0
      val maxSize = 1024

      val flow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = Flow[ByteString]
        .map((in: ByteString) => {
          val left = maxSize - totalSize
          if (left > 0) {
            val takeNow =
              if (in.size > left) {
                in.slice(0, left)
              } else {
                in
              }
            data.append(takeNow)
            totalSize += takeNow.size
          }
          in
        })

      val accumulatorWithResult: Accumulator[ByteString, Result] = accumulator.through(flow).map { result =>
        logger.info(s"The flow has completed and the result is $result")
        if (result.header.status >= 400) {
          val headerText = data.map(_.utf8String).mkString("")
          logger.warn(s"There was an error. Request head: $headerText")
        }
        result
      }

      accumulatorWithResult.recover {
        case error =>
          val headerText = data.map(_.utf8String).mkString("")
          logger.warn(s"There was an error: $error. Request head: $headerText")
          throw error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for a simple Filter you need a .failed.foreach call on the result future:

```
class LoggingFilter @Inject() (val mat: Materializer, implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    val eventualResult = nextFilter(requestHeader)

    eventualResult.failed.foreach { error: Throwable =>
      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and " +
        s"returned 500 $error")
    }

    eventualResult.map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and " +
        s"returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```